# Handling multiple forms interacting with the same model in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, activerecord, model

I have an app that is dealing with "patients". Each patient is going to have three forms that they deal with initially. Each form has related questions, but they also have differences, so they can't be the same form. Each answer, even if it is for the same question, has to be recorded and archived. Also, there needs to be some sense of versioning to each form that is filled out. For instance if patient "Steve" fills out "Form 1" on "October 5th", and a question is taken away from the form the next day, I need to still be able to pull up the questions that Steve filled out on Form 1. Right now I have four models that I think solve this problem which are:

patients: first_name, last_name

forms: name, version

form_response: patient_id, form_id

questions: content, form_id

answers: response, question_id, form_response_id

Would this be the best way to map out this data set? Also, should this all be handled through the patient model? If not, what type of model structure should be used to handle this? I'm just really confused on how to best handle this situation as far as what should go where and not end up with a mess of code to maintain. Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You have the right ides. Starting from the top:

**form**

- has_many questions

**questions**

- belong_to form
- has_many answers

**answers**

- belong_to question
- belong_to response

Then you tie it together with the response:

**response**

- belongs_to patient
- belongs_to form

Comment: Thank you so much for the response. That is great to know that I am on the right track. As far as how to handle this in the models, what do you think a good strategy would be? Would it be to handle everything through the patient model, or to delegate outside of it?

Comment: @sturoid If it were me, I would let the form handle all of this, and store the patient id in a session (or something), then create the response at the end. Nested model forms are also going to be your friend here: http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looking into form objects to make this a lot easier.  You might want to checkout:

[Form-backing objects for fun and profit](http://pivotallabs.com/form-backing-objects-for-fun-and-profit/)

[Rails Form Objects](https://medium.com/p/84b6849c886e)

[Form Objects](http://railscasts.com/episodes/416-form-objects)

Comment: I was really leaning towards this method. How would you handle the routing and controller/controllers actions for this? So I will have 3 forms that all want to interact with the Patient model. Would you use a new controller and or controllers as well?